# Keytool command not recognized

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-plus

I'm working on Login with Google+ activity and when I write command "Keytool" in Cmd this message appears: "keytool is not recognized  as an internal or external command".

How do I fix this problem ?

Comment: What have you tried? An example would be very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Keytool command can only be ran if you have added it to your path or from within the directory where it is located.

If you are on Windows, most likely it is located here:

*C:\Program Files\Java\\bin*

You'll need to either run the keytool command from there, or add the keytool location to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: If you're working with Android, the keytool path is in the jdk - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk[jdk_version]\bin